# How to search multiple excel workbooks for a specific vba macro text string

Tags: excel, vba, macos, full-text-search

I have a folder containing over 200 workbooks.  One of them has a specific VBA macro that I am looking for.  Is there a way to search multiple workbooks for a text string from specific macro program for sub routine?  I really don’t want to have to open each workbook, open the VBE and search for the string one at a time.  Thanks!

Comment: search VBE automation.

Comment: Start here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.htm

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40613854/4088852) is essentially what you're after, minus a Workbook loop - just test for your macro declaration instead of a comment.